# IDEA java always generate private methods

Tags: java, intellij-idea

As title says, when I use short cut `command + N` to generate such as `Constructor`, `getter`, I always get private methods however I want public one.

Does anyone knows how to configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Editor -> code style -> Java -> code generation -> set default visibility
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In `Settings → Editor → Code Style → <language>`, go to the `Code Generation` tab and make sure that `Default Visibility` is set to `Public`:

[image]